# Toggle between buttons after waiting for collapse animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make two buttons that can toggle in between each other and also both could be unselected. I have the current code working for the general desired behavior, but I want to wait for the collapsing animation to finish before toggling to the other state. Essentially, the `'Creating Room'` and `'Joining Room'` cards should not overlap, i.e, one should wait for the other one to be completely hidden before opening up.

I have tried fiddling around with the events found here (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#events), but my solution is not able to handle the case where both buttons becomes unselected.

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg mr-3" onclick="collapse('create')">
  Create Room
</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg ml-3" onclick="collapse('join')">
  Join Room
</button>

<div class="collapse" id="create">
  <div class="card card-body mt-3">
    Creating Room
  </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="join">
  <div class="card card-body mt-3">
    Joining Room
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function collapse(id) {
    $('#create').collapse('hide');
    $('#join').collapse('hide');
    $('#'+id).collapse('toggle')

    $('#join').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
        // Something here?
    })

    $('#create').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
        // Something here?
    })
}
```

Without listening for `hidden.bs.collapse`, the collapsing animation does not finish before showing the other option.

With the listener, I am unable to find a way that handles both options being unselected.

Here is `jsfiddle` with the complete code: https://jsfiddle.net/pLt89cyh/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to check if there is any visible element with class `.collapse` that is not the target of the current clicked `button`. Note I have used `data-target` attribute to maintain the relation between the buttons and they target. Now, if there is any visible element with class `.collapse` that is not the target, then you toggle that element first and listen for the event `hidden.bs.collapse` before showing the target one, for this we use [JQuery.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/). Otherwise, we just toggle the target element.

## Example:

```js
$(".btn").click(function()
{
    // Don't do anything when some element is in the collapsing transition.
    if ($(".collapsing").length > 0) return;

    var target = $(this).data('target');
    var others = $(".collapse.show:not(" + target + ")");

    if (others.length > 0)
    {
        others.collapse("hide").one("hidden.bs.collapse", function()
        {
            $(target).collapse("show");
        });
    }
    else
    {
        $(target).collapse('toggle');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">

<button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg mr-3" data-target="#create">
  Create Room
</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg ml-3" data-target="#join">
  Join Room
</button>
<button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg ml-3" data-target="#leave">
  Leave Room
</button>

<div class="collapse" id="create">
  <div class="card card-body mt-3">
    Creating Room
  </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="join">
  <div class="card card-body mt-3">
    Joining Room
  </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="leave">
  <div class="card card-body mt-3">
    Leaving Room
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Note how this is easily extensible to more buttons, like shown on the previous example.

Comment: Thanks, it works for the most part, except when you pressed the buttons in quick succession. To fix this, I added `data-parent` to the collapsible items and set the parent to be the ID of a `div` wrapped around all the buttons and the collapsible items.

Comment: I have updated the answer to prevent this situation, detecting if there is some element that is in the animation transition state. Those elements will have the `.collapsing` class.

Comment: Yes, that is also a good solution I came across as well. With that solution, one can also validate that no other actions can interrupt the animation (such as a button toggle going to the `active` state).